# Issues with the viewer in TeXworks

Tags: viewers, texworks

I've just switched from mac to windows and have just started using TeXworks. I like it, but I find that the default pdf viewer is difficult to use. For example, there doesn't seem to be a key command for going to the bottom or top of the current page; I can't view pages continuously; spacebar does nothing for navigation; and trackpad functionality appears to be broken (scrolling with the trackpad causes the pages to jump around in a seemingly random fashion). Is there a list of key commands somewhere? Or is there a way of using a different default pdf viewer?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no continous viewing yet, though it is planned for version 0.6: http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/Roadmap#0.6_series

Comment: looking forward to continuous scrolling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since using a different viewer is an option, I'll add how I do it.

First, I disable the "automatic preview":

> Preferences -> Typesetting -> Select your typesetting option -> Edit -> uncheck View PDF after running

Second, I use an external PDF viewer that can work with PDF files being updated. For linux, Acrobat works this way, in Windows it does not AFAIK. You can use for instance SumatraPDF.

---

Some might say that it's annoying, but I like TeXworks, and sometimes I even use the internal viewer. This is when I make only a small change in the document. The good zoom feature of the TeXworks viewer makes it very fast to check that the correction was successful.

Comment: Ah, very nice. That works. I found that SumatraPDF supports continuous updating, so this is a good solution. One more question: is there any way to tell TeXworks not to automatically open the pdf in the default viewer when you first open the tex file?

Comment: @ChuckHague no, as far as I know, I always have to close it. But I got used to this problem. Maybe we can mail a feature request for this. And thank, I'll add SumatraPDF into the answer.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Thanks for the helpful information!

Comment: Little late to the game, but the latest version of TeXworks has a check box "Open corresponding PDF preview with TeX files" that you can uncheck that will keep TeXworks from opening the PDF file when you open the .TeX file.

Comment: @LloydChristmas - Isn't this what [Greg answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134334/67605) on Sep '13?

Answer (score 4):

In preferences -> general -> untick open corresponding PDF preview with TeX files will not open the internal pdf viewer when you open any .tex file. Interestingly, I find windows 7 does not like two instances of the same program opening at the same time so have to use sumatrapdf as well.

Greg

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.