# Configuring TeXworks with SumatraPDF

Tags: texworks, sumatrapdf

I have TeXworks for creating and viewing LaTeX documents, and that is working great.

A while ago, I also downloaded SumatraPDF viewer because some people told me it was better than other ones.

I am wondering (1) if there's any advantage to using SumatraPDF instead of the build-in viewer that came with TeXworks, and (2) how to do that, if it's a good plan.

Please note that I'm a total computer newbie, I don't know what "DDE" commands are, and I couldn't understand most of what I read in related posts from this (and other) forums. Also I am not interested in spending money, and I will be using these programs primarily for creating mathematics articles. And I'm on a Windows computer. I have Adobe Reader too for viewing docs, but I was told SumatraPDF is faster.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Related Thread http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95380/issues-with-the-viewer-in-texworks/95382#95382

Comment: I'm using TexStudio and Sumatra and I really like the way these two programs can be combined. TexStudio also has a built-in viewer but I like the way Sumatra can be controlled much more. 
If you need a good explanation how to set up TexStudio and Sumatra you can have a look here: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/texstudio-sumatrapdf/

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: [Suppress TeXworks PDF preview](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44405/suppress-texworks-pdf-preview). If you use those instructions and manually open the PDF in Sumatra, it'll reload the updated PDF whenever it changes. Also, Adobe Reader is more of a pain to integrate with, since it locks the PDF from being modified while it's open, unlike Sumatra.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Yes that's why I wanted to use Sumatra. Is there a way to make it the default? That's the part I couldn't figure out.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to make TeXWorks use an alternate viewer.